# Каково происхождение фразеологизма: "В каждой бочке затычка"?

Tags: фразеология

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Происхождение-то достаточно прозрачно. В винных (и не только) бочках зытычки всегда подбирались и подгонялись индивидуально. Так что "каждой бочке затычка" - это вполне про тех, кто постоянно суется не в своё дело, хвататется за все дела сразу вопреки своим реальным возможностям или просто ввязывается во все разговоры, лезет ко всем в друзья и проч.

Вопрос, имхо, надо ставить о том, почему выражение стало столь популярным. Но тут остаётся только гадать. Возможно у фразы есть конкретный автор, пустивший её "в народ", но никаких следов этого на поверхности не обнаруживается.

Answer (score 1):

Бегемотус мудро написал, мняк мудро заметил, запускаем новый лозунг: Миру -мир! Крыму - Крым! А каждой бочке - затычка!

Answer (score 0):

Вот именно - не "В каждой бочке затычка", а "Каждой бочке затычка".

Comment: Викисловарь одно выражение ставит другому в синонимы. Хотя я скептически к нему отношусь, думаю в этот раз можно принять за чистую монету.